# iText and HTML tags

Tags: java, itext

I need to know if someone can help me about this cool free PDF generator: iText using JAVA.
My request is this: I've a string with html tags such as:

```
<bold>Hi everyone</bolddd>, my name is <italic>Maurice</italic>.
```

Is possible to "parse" my string and make the PDF with the correct output about the font (bold, italic, etc etc etc)??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try this: http://javaxtendsolutions.wordpress.com/2011/01/03/itext-1-5-html-to-pdf/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try the below code...

```
     String htmlString="<bold>Hi everyone</bolddd>, my name is <italic>Maurice</italic>";
     ArrayList p=new ArrayList();

     StringReader strReader = new StringReader(htmlString);
     Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 20, 20, 20, 50);
     PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("filename.pdf"));
     document.open();
     -------
     -------              
     p = HTMLWorker.parseToList(strReader, null);
     Paragraph paragraph=new paragraph();
     for (int k = 0; k < p.size(); ++k){
         paragraph.add((com.lowagie.text.Element)p.get(k));
     }
     document.add(paragraph);

     ------- 
     -------
     document.close();
```

Hope this helps...